# frontend instances VS backend instances

Tags: google-app-engine, cloud

What is the difference between Frontend instances and Backend instances in Google App Engine? What purpose is each good for?

I have tried reading some stuff from [Developer's Guide](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/) and I searched google, but I got mainly pricing issues and no technical difference.

Comment: Try the documentation page on Instances--in particular the section titled [Types of Instances](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/adminconsole/instances.html#Types_of_Instances).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Have a look at https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/adminconsole/instances. Mainly, the frontend instance is for serving time-sensitive requests, for example, web requests. It has a deadline limited (probably 30 secs). The backend instance is for serving not time-sensitive requests, for example, cron jobs.